# Swift Compiler Error - Xcode 6

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors, xcode6, compiler-warnings

Can anyone please tell me what this compiler error means?

[image]

Comment: Two files are missing. Did you move them or delete accidentally ?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your build?

Comment: I think I deleted them accidentally so i have to start again...d'oh! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new project (just a Hello World app) and see if it works. If it does you may have to recreate this current project which will involve a lot of copy and past. Be sure you do not delete any files from the project unless you know what your doing deleting them. If you cant get the Hello World test to compile then you may have to reinstall x-code.